(LARAVEL) Error when making POST requests. Azure VPC production application (webapp and mysql database flexible)
I deployed a laravel application through the azure VPC (azure web app and azure mysql database flexible).
I am encountering an error when making post type requests, even with the environment variables defined in the azure panel, the developer tools reports errors such as: The “XSRF-TOKEN” cookie was rejected for having an invalid domain.

Do I need to change any session.php settings?
Add another environment variable?

My program normally runs on my domain and with https, the problem is trying to log in and having the request rejected. I added features like logs to return errors and return which request it was, but I noticed that the request is refused.

PS: the browser itself reports that the connection is not secure, possibly my route in the form sends it as http instead of https, I've already tried changing the action to the URI, anyway. Can you help me?

My Request:
` <?php
         namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter; 
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;



class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 */
public function authorize(): bool
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'username' => ['required', 'string'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string']
    ];
}

public function authenticate(): void
{

    if(!Auth::attempt($this->only('username', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))){
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter::hit($this->chave());

        throw \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::withMessages([
            'username' => 'Email Incorreto',
            'password' => 'Senha Incorreta',
        ]);


    }
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter::clear($this->chave());
}

public function limitacao():void
{
    if(!\Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($this->chave(), 3)){
        return;
    }
    event(new Lockout($this));

    $seconds = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter::availableIn($this->chave());

    throw \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::withMessages([
        'username' => trans('auth.chave', [
            'seconds' => $seconds,
            'minutes' => ceil($seconds / 60)
        ])
    ]);
}

public function chave():string
{
    return \Illuminate\Support\Str::transliterate(\Illuminate\Support\Str::lower($this->string('username')). '|' .$this->ip());
}

}
`
My Controller (method):
   public function autenticar(LoginRequest $request)
   {
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    $msg = 'Bem vindo administrador!';
    session()->flash('message', $msg);

    return redirect()->route('dashboard.index');
}

My routes:
    //rota de login
     Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class , 'index'])->name('login');
     Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'autenticar'])->name('postLogin');

My form:
           <form class="border-dark-subtle border w-50 p-5 d-flex flex-column align-items-center             justify-content-center gap-5 rounded rounded-3" action="{{route('postLogin')}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <span class="fs-1 fw-bold text-info">LOGIN</span>
            <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100 gap-3">
                <!-- Inserir Email -->
                <div class="form-floating w-100">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Email" name="username">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    @if($errors->has('username') && $errors->has('username'))
                        @if($errors->has('username'))
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{$errors->first('username')}}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    @endif

                </div>

                <!-- Inserir Senha -->
                <div class="form-floating w-100">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Senha"
                           name="password">
                    <label>Senha</label>
                    @if($errors->has('password') && $errors->has('password'))
                        @if($errors->has('password'))
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{$errors->first('password')}}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    @endif

                </div>
            </div>
                <label class="alert alert-info" id="numeroLabel" for="">{{$numero_aleatorio}}</label>
            <div class="form-floating w-100 mt-0">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="teste" name="">
                <div id="mensagemErro" class="alert alert-danger d-none">Confirme o número acima</div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="mt-5 btn btn-info text-light px-5 py-3 fs-5">Entrar</button>

        </form>

PS: Don't pay attention to some passages written in another language. I am Brazilian :)
I tried to directly pass the https:// route in my form but it also resulted in an error. I read the documentation but I don't understand what I need to do, and if it's even there. If necessary, I have these environment variables in my Azure panel

APP_NAME
APP_ENV
APP_KEY
APP_DEBUG
APP_TIMEZONE
APP_URL
Also those for database configuration and logs.

NOTE: The database works correctly. I inserted a forced seeder and ran it via my ssh server. When opening Azure Data Studio I could see my insertion. Thanks

Generally speaking, cookies are not relevant to Laravel beyond the one that holds the session ID. If you are setting a "XSRF-TOKEN" cookie somewhere in your code, you don't need to. The CSRF token is submitted with the form data. What is the error behaviour you're seeing from Laravel?

In the meantime I'm voting to close this as needing focus, you've asked 4 different questions here. Step one should be to fix your HTTPS; this is trivial with free managed TLS certificates that I assume your hosting provider can handle for you.
